# Jquery refreshes and loads the page with table

Tags: jquery, html, grails, gsp

I'm having some problem with my Jquery. So, the problem is that whenever i submit the form and get the tables of result. My page refreshes and is unable to load the result in the Jquery dialog box. This is my codes

```
<script>
    $(function () {
      $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 600,
        width: 1000,
        show: "blind",
        hide: ""
      });

      $("#opener").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        return true;
      });
    });
</script>
```

For my html:

```
<form id="searchtable" >

              <label>Search by Username :</label><input type ="text" name="searchid" style="border: 1px solid black">

                <input  type ="submit" name ="search" id="opener">
                <br>
                <%-- search table --%>
                  Results:
                  <div id="dialog" title="Search Result">
                  <table border ="1" id="normal">
                  <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <th>ID</th>
                              <th>Username</th>


                          </tr>
                  </tbody>

                  <g:each in = "${example}">
                          <tr>
                              <td>${it.ID}</td>
                              <td>${it.username}</td>

                         </tr>
                  </g:each>
                  </table>
                  </div>

              <%--List Table--%>
               <table border ="1" id="normal">
               <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <th>ID</th>
                          <th>Username</th>

                      </tr>
                </tbody>
              <g:each in = "${result}">
                        <tr>

                          <td>${it.ID}</td>
                          <td>${it.username}</td>

                        </tr>
              </g:each>
            </table>
    </form>
```

So after submitting the values, i need to process the values in the controller and pass it back to the html to display it out. But it just refreshes and can't get it load. So anyone knows what to do? I just need it to load after the form submit -> refreshes -> dialog box appear with results. Thank you guys so much

Comment: need to use AJAX to submit form if you don't want page to refresh

Comment: Any idea on how I should do it? I did read up on Ajax but I can't find any example that is similar to mine.

Comment: not sure why yours is any different than any other AJAX form submit. Submit the form and return the table html you want. Place the html in container it needs to go in using success callback

Comment: Do you have any good examples that I can look into? I tried some others but not success callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this :

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 600,
        width: 1000,
        show: "blind",
        hide: ""
    });

    $("#searchtable").on('submit', function() {
        alert("submit handler has fired");
        $.ajax({
            url: ...,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: ...,
            success: function(html){
                //do something with the `html` returned from the server here
                alert(html);
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
        return false;//suppress natural form submission
    });
});
```

With reference to the jQuery's [$.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you will have to fill in the gaps.

Comment: sorry what is the type about? I dont have any idea after reading the documentation

Comment: `type` should be "GET" or "POST". These are two ways of packaging the data into the request. Your server-side code may be written to expect either GET or POST data. If in doubt, try "GET" first.

Comment: Hi, I've tried your code but it doesn't seem to work as i click on the button.

Comment: How far does it get? What tests have you run?

Comment: //do something with the `html` returned from the server here
idk what to do here.. and the button doesnt submit or pops up anything...

Comment: To debug, simply `alert(html);`

Comment: I have edited above to add an error handler and several debug alerts.

Comment: Hi it say no error found, btw i added another alert into the success: function but there was no popup.

Comment: Does `alert(html)`display the expected result? Did `$("#dialog").dialog("open")` work before you introduced the ajax? Does the page actually have a block element with `id="dialog"`?

Comment: ahhh everything works now. now the problem is it didnt put out the desirable table result, instead it loaded the whole webpage.

Comment: the other thing is im not sure what to input here
                //do something with the `html` returned from the server here

Comment: Now you know that the server returns the correct HTML, try @JustinPrince's solution.

Comment: I've already tried his solution, but well, all I get is the webpage coming out instead of the desired <div> dialog box with the results in it.

Comment: Then, try replacing `$("#dialog").dialog("open")` with `$("#dialog").html(html).dialog("open")`.

Comment: I tried this on your code, it still gives me a webpage.. Is it because of the URL? I put the web link the same as on the webpage.

Comment: url: "/test/Admin/main",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: "GET",
            success: function(html){
                //do something with the `html` returned from the server here
                alert(html);
                $("#dialog").html(html).dialog("open")
            },

Comment: I don't understand. Several comments ago you said "ahhh everything works now .... ". ie you devised a way to return just the HTML fragment of interest, NOT the whole page. Why have you done to make the behaviour revert?

Comment: The client-side code is correct, subject possibly to getting the URL right. It seems you need to fix things server-side, about which I have no knowledge. I can't help any more.

Comment: erm, I kind of fixed it, I just recreated another page with just the table in it. Thank you so much for your help beetroot :)

Comment: Hi beetroot, is it okay if you would help me in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574205/using-jquery-modal-box-and-ajax-to-display-values-from-cell-table thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery's load() function, you can send a request to the intended controller and have it render an HTML response (the contents of the dialog), which will be loaded into the #dialog element upon a successful response.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
      $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 600,
        width: 1000,
        show: "blind",
        hide: ""
      });

      $('#searchtable').submit( function () {
        var searchId = $('input[name="searchid"]').val();
        $('#dialog').load('/url/to/controller', { "searchid": searchId }, function () {
          $(this).dialog('open');
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Erm, may I know what is the #dialogue about?

Comment: Okay thank you so much! btw the path controller includes the full path from folders? Cause the dialog box opens and doesnt render the codes

Comment: It's request URL to the controller.

Comment: I dont have any request url to the controller :\ . i tried putting my on page url and it loaded the whole page link.. oh btw my title of the dialog box went missing after i click it on the second time... is there any solution to this?