# Using jquery modal box and ajax to display values from cell table

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, grails, modal-dialog

I'm trying to do an UPDATE function by using Jquery modal dialog box to pass the values to the controller. However, I'm displaying my values in a HTML table box, is there a way to pass the values from the table row to the modal box? I want to do it in a way when i click the row, the values will be displayed in the modal. I'm also unsure of how to link a jquery dialog box to a table row.

This is the table

[image]

These are the codes for it

```
<form id="searchtable" >
               <%--List Table--%>
               <table border = 1 cellpadding = 2  cellspacing = 2 id="normal">
              <tr>
                 <th width=9.7%>ID</th>
                 <th width=24%>Username</th>     
                 <th width=13%>Account ID</th>
                 <th width=29%>Email</th>
                 <th width=10%>User ID</th>
                 <th width=12%>Device ID</th>         
              </tr>
         </table>

              <div style="height: 250px; overflow: scroll; width: 100%;">
              <table id="normal">
              <g:each in = "${result}">
              <tr>
              <td width=10%>${it.ID}</td>
              <td width=25%>${it.Username}</td>
              <td width=13.5%>${it.account_id}</td>
              <td width=30.5%>${it.email}</td>
              <td width=10.5%>${it.user_id}</td>
              <td width=13%>${it.device_id }</td>
              </tr>
              </g:each>


              </table>
         </div>        
    </form>
```

This is an example of the dialog box of how it should appear

[image]

Thank you guys so much. If needed, I can provide you guys with the codes.

Comment: This sounds very easy to do .. where is your code that creates the modal?  Which of the table rows should be used?

Comment: Give me a minute and I will update on this. Oh ya sorry to update you. I have no idea how to link a click function to a tr row so that when i click the row, the jquery modal box pops out. As for the dialog box that i have screenshot, that is another box that creates user. What I'm trying to do here is when i click the row, the box pops out, and the values are inside, its use to EDITUSER.

Answer (score 1):

use .btn class to your tr and inclose your username value to

```
<span class="username">${it.username}</span>
```

your jquery should

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn tr").live("click", function{
    var name = $(this).find(".username").text();
    ...put your code here that will update your table...
  });
});
```

if you click the tr, it will find its child with class "username" and will get the data for you.

Comment: Hi but my 'button' is actually a row.. should I place the ID at my <tr> tag or? and I have to submit the form in order to update the table.

Comment: Yes, that should also work. You can use this if you want: $('#btn tr').click(function () { ...your code here... });

Comment: Thanks I will try it out. as for the 'var name = $("#username").val();' this line refers to the table values? and how do i put the values into the modal dialog box?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, I updated my answer already. Hope that helps. :)

Comment: '<span class="username">${id.username}</span>' is it ok if I switch the <span> to <td>? Thank you so much, I will go and try it :)

Comment: No, I mean this <td><span class="username">${it.username}</span></td>.

Comment: Btw is it id.username or it.username? is there a difference?

Comment: Oh, sorry, typo. But I know you get it :)